# How to jump between different sections of code?

Tags: java, goto

I have the following program structure:

```
outerLoop:
for (i =0; i<x; i++) {
    if(check condition) {
       a = /* do something to calculate a */
       goto jump;
    } else {
        //do something else
    }
}

jump:
if (check condition) {
   //do something
   goto outerLoop;
}
```

So like seen above, I want to transfer the control from the `if` part of `for` loop to the `if` condition seen outside the loop. And I want to again jump to the `for` loop from the `if` statement. How do I do that? Is there a `goto` statement in Java?

Comment: you can use function calls.

Comment: Or just `break` if it's as simple as the code shown here. Labels and goto are not used in most modern programming languages.

Comment: Obligatory: [*A Case against the GO TO Statement*](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD02xx/EWD215.html)

Comment: @Bill Im sorry if this is a stupid question! But how do I use function calls here?

Comment: It's hard to tell what you *should* do instead of `goto`, because it's not at all clear what you want to accomplish here. Mostly because your code isn't anywhere near valid Java, is indented wonkily, and contains nothing besides control flow.

Comment: We can help in a better way if you can show us some real code.

Comment: @confusopoly Anytime you use `break` it's probably better to just split off the loop into a function and use `return` to make it explicit what the result of the "breakable" computation was, if any.

Comment: @millimoose Good point. That makes it shorter and easier to grasp than the break, especially with a good function name.

Comment: I took a stab at fixing your code, but because pretty much none of your braces were balanced or anything indented in any sane way, it might not be how you intended it.

Comment: @user93665        Sorry to be a late follower on this, but isn't that the first thing that Guru's teach you,"Don't make a sphagetti of your program by using JUMPs"...and I mean precisely in high-level code such as C/C++/Java?

Comment: @hagubear In fact programs like what this would have been are specifically why gotos aren't in java

Comment: @hagubear Don't know about your "gurus" (ugh) but ours just went with never introducing the concept. There is one valid use of `goto` in C but that involves shared cleanup code before returning which would be clunky to express by adding another intermediate function. (Java has `try..finally` for this though.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to jump using break and labels when you have multiple nested for loops.

see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

Example from link:

```
class BreakWithLabelDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int[][] arrayOfInts =
        {
            { 32,  87,   3,    589 },
            { 12,  1076, 2000, 8   },
            { 622, 127,  77,   955 }
        };

        int searchfor = 12;
        int i;
        int j = 0;
        boolean foundIt = false;

        search:
            for (i = 0; i < arrayOfInts.length; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j < arrayOfInts[i].length; j++)
                {
                    if (arrayOfInts[i][j] == searchfor)
                    {
                        foundIt = true;
                        break search;
                    }
                }
            }

        if (foundIt)
        {
            System.out.println("Found " + searchfor + " at " + i + ", " + j);
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(searchfor + " not in the array");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can someone fix the formatting, it's impossible from iphone :(

Answer (score 2):

Going against the other answers: don't use `break` either. I *think* what you're trying to accomplish here can be done this way:

```
int calculateA() {
    for (i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        if (/* a was found */) {
            return a;
        } else {
            // do something else
        }
    // What to do when `a` is not found is now explicit
    throw new Exception("cannot calculate a");
}

// OuterLoop should be an actual loop
int a = calculateA();
while (/* second condition */) {
    a = calculateA();
}
```

Comment: Agreed 99 times of of 100 a break is unnessisary.

Answer (score 1):

Java does not support `goto` (although this is a reserved word). However java as other c-like languages supports `break` and `continue`. You need `break` here. It escapes from the loop.

In contrary to C java has `break` with label that is "almost" `goto` but limited. It is useful when you want to escape from several nested loops.

Comment: You can use `break` to break a block of code as well :) .. `label:{statement1; if(condition) break label; statement2;}`

Answer (score 0):

`break` or `continue`, according what you need to do.

see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462373/difference-between-break-and-continue-statement) post for the diffrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can use function calls to jump between statements accompanied by `break` and `continue`.
 See if this helps:

```
for (i =0; i<x;i++){
if(check condition)
{
   /*do something
   calculate 'a'
   */
   jump();
   break; //use break if you want to exit the loop
}
else 
//do something else
}//method ends 


void jump()
{
   if(check condition)
   //do something
}
```