# Continue statement works but break statement doesn't work the way it should

Tags: java

I was writing code to generate the prime numbers using nested loops in Java and with the help of a friend I made a program which successfully generates prime numbers.

In this code my friend suggested that I use `continue label` statement to transfer the control to outer loop and it works. However, when I replace the `continue` statement with `break`, it doesn't give me the answer it should. Can anyone please explain what is the mistake or the reason behind this behavior?

The code is:

```
import java.io.*;
class Prime
{    
    public static void main(String x[]) throws Exception
    {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int n = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        outer:  for (int i = 2; i<=n;i++)
            {
                for(int j = 2; j<i;j++)
                {
                    if(i%j==0)
                    {   
                        continue outer;
                    }

                }
                System.out.println("Prime Number " + i);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: [You need to understand the basic difference between a break and a continue in that case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/462373/2024761).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the situation (check the comments for descriptions of what will happen):

```
outer:  for (int i = 2; i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 2; j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {   
                continue outer; // skip the rest of outers loop and go to its start
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime Number " + i); //this will not get run 
                                                 //when the continue statement is hit
    }
```

With break:

```
outer:  for (int i = 2; i<=n;i++)
    {
        for(int j = 2; j<i;j++)
        {
            if(i%j==0)
            {   
                break; // stop running the inner loop
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Prime Number " + i); //this still gets run regardless of break
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not 100% clear from the question, when you say `replace continue statement with break` does that mean your line went from:

```
if(i%j==0)
{   
    continue outer;
}
```

To:

```
if(i%j==0)
{   
    break outer;
}
```

because if so you have instructed the program to `break` the outer loop and thus execution of both loops will stop

Comment: No i mean if(i%j==0) { break;}

Comment: @user3247825 , ok in that case you have instructed the program to stop executing the inner loop, thus running `System.out.println("Prime Number " + i);`before running the next iteration of the `outer` loop. With `continue outer;` you have told the program to jump to the top of the `outer loop` which will skip the execution of line `System.out.println("Prime Number " + i);`

Comment: Thanks for the help Sir. It really helps me in understanding the behavior of the code.

Answer (score 0):

`continue` start over;

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){ 
continue; // restart iteration with next value in index i=1;
}
```

`break`  execute code after loop

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)) { 
break; // execute from  from next line
}
```

// next line