# My loop is only checking the first array item

Tags: java, loops, bukkit

My loop is only checking the first item of the array, which makes my code fail each time:

```
String igitems = "IgnoredItems";
String items = getConfig().getString("IgnoredItems.itemid");
items = items + args[0] + ",";
String[] myarray = items.split(",");
for(String fitem : myarray) {
    if(!fitem.equals(args[0])){
        getConfig().set(igitems + ".itemid", items);
        saveConfig();
        reloadConfig();
        sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GREEN + "Added " + ChatColor.GOLD + args[0] + ChatColor.GREEN + " to ignore list.");
        break;
   } else {
        sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + "Item is already in the list");
        break;
    }
}
```

If I add `system.out.print(myarray);` after `String[] myarray = items.split(",");` it shows the entire array, which is right:

```
1:0
2:0
5:0
8:0
5:0
```

But, when I add `system.out.print(fitem);` after `for(String fitem : myarray){` it shows only the first item from the array (1:0) wich makes my code fail almost each time except if it's the first item.

Comment: Does it make sense to `break` in both the `if` and the `else` part?

Comment: It should only find the item once, if it finds it, that's why I break it.

Comment: you are breaking on if AND else. So you are checking the first element and it results in a break, even if it isnt equal. delete the break from the `else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the loop with

```
                    if(!items.contains(args[0] + ",")){
                        getConfig().set(igitems + ".itemid", items + args[0] + ",");
                        saveConfig();
                        sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GREEN + "Added " + ChatColor.GOLD + args[0] + ChatColor.GREEN + " to ignore list.");
                    }  else {
                        sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + "Item (" + ChatColor.GOLD + args[0] + ChatColor.RED + ") is already in the list !");
                    }
```

and it worked fine, solved.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking the loop. I dont know in which case you want to break the loop but even if `fitem.equals(args[0])` or `!fitem.equals(args[0])` you are invoking the break.

Maybe you just want to break the else case?

```
if(!Arrays.asList(my).contains(args[0])){
    getConfig().set(igitems + ".itemid", items);
    saveConfig();
    reloadConfig();
    sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.GREEN + "Added " + ChatColor.GOLD + args[0] + ChatColor.GREEN + " to ignore list.");
}else{
    sender.sendMessage(prefix + ChatColor.RED + "Item is already in the list")
}
```

A `break` will return from the nearest loop. So in your case you stop iterating through `for(String fitem : myarray)` A `continue` instead will immediatly go one step ahead in your loop

Comment: It should only find the string one time, so once I found it I can break it.

Comment: So you are trying to find the Element which equals args[0]?

Comment: My command should add stuff to a config file, but if it already exists, shows a message then exit out.

Comment: @davidp027 if my understanding of your task is correct see the edited answer.

Comment: So then please update your question and clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63732/discussion-between-user-and-davidp027).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462373/781965) and its answers - you're `break` statements are causing this behaviour. You probably want `continue` or just nothing at all, since that would have the same behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `,` after and not between.

```
String items = getConfig().getString("IgnoredItems.itemid");
// Wrong
items = items + args[0] + ",";
// Ok
if (items.isEmpty()) {
    items = args[0];
} else {
    items = items + "," + args[0];
}
```

However, review your entire approach.
See [`MemorySection.getStringList(String)`](http://jd.bukkit.org/dev/apidocs/org/bukkit/configuration/MemorySection.html#getStringList%28java.lang.String%29).

```
List<String> items = getConfig().getStringList("IgnoredItems.itemid");
items.add(args[0]);
getConfig().set("IgnoredItems.itemid", items);
```