# How to manually exit a while loop (java)

Tags: java, exception, while-loop

This code will take user input from the console, and go to one of two places depending on if the input is an Integer or not. The exception is caught and then dealt with by reading it again to get it out of the stream. (not sure if Scanner counts as a stream, but I know that without the input.next() it will never leave that section).

So what I want to know is how can I exit the loop if I get to the MismatchException with a certain input. I've tested the if(bad_input == anything) and it turns out I can never actually get there. I tried some print statements in that block that never executed. Would appreciate any help.

**Solved**

Not sure how to close the question, but this has been solved. I was incorrectly using == to check two strings. The correct way is to use bad_input.equals("x").

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  //read input from console
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

  boolean loop = true;

  while(loop){
    //inputting "1 2 d 1" will evaluate each term separately and output at once
    try{

      //choice = console input only in INTEGER
      int choice = input.nextInt();
      System.out.println("Input was " + choice);

    } catch (InputMismatchException ex){
      //here if input != INTEGER

      String bad_input = input.next();
      System.out.println("Bad Input: " + bad_input);

      //need to figure out how to exit loop!!
      if(bad_input == "x"){
           loop = false;
           return;
      }
      continue;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Use break instead of continue, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462373/difference-between-break-and-continue-statement

Comment: The continue is there for if the "bad input" is something other than the exit condition "x". I want it to continue iterating until I receive the "x".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In java String comparison is using equals function "==" might not work

Change

```
if (bad_input == "x") {
    loop = false;
    return;
}
```

To

```
if (bad_input.equals("x")) {
    loop = false;
    return;
}
```

Comment: This is the one. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use break.

```
if(condition)
    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

`break;` will exit the loop immediately. What you're doing should also work though. I'm not sure you need the `if` statement though, the whole catch block will be executed if and only if the input isn't an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Well I think you need to use

```
 if(bad_input.equals("x")){
       loop = false;
       return;
  }
```

== checks for same reference

.equals checks for same values

http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/java-questions/java-whats-the-difference-between-equals-and/

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use **equalsIgnoreCase** method.

```
if (bad_input.equalsIgnoreCase("x")) {
```

And to exit the loop at any value other then integer, you can simply use **break**.

```
catch (InputMismatchException ex) {
                // here if input != INTEGER

                String bad_input = input.next();
                System.out.println("Bad Input: " + bad_input);

                break;
            }
```