# trying to break a while loop with a switch case inside switch case

Tags: java, while-loop, switch-statement

I am receiving some data from an USB component, component will send me continuous data, if I have received the data I have to stop reading the data myself and the component will not stop sending data, I am trying to break the loop if I received some key I tried using boolean, but it is not terminating the loop.

```
 boolean shouldBreak = false;

    switch(msg.what)
    {               

    case USBAccessoryWhat:
    switch(((USBAccessoryManagerMessage)msg.obj).type) {
    case READ:
        if(accessoryManager.isConnected() == false) {
            return;
        }
        while(true) {
            if(accessoryManager.available() < 2) {
                break;
            }

            switch(commandPacket[0]){
                case 0:
                    test = Integer.toString(commandPacket[0]) + ", " + Integer.toString(commandPacket[1]);
                    Test_one(test);
                break;
                case 1:
                    test = Integer.toString(commandPacket[0]) + ", " + Integer.toString(commandPacket[1]);
                    Test_one(test);
                break;
                case 2:
                    test = Integer.toString(commandPacket[0]) + ", " + Integer.toString(commandPacket[1]);
                    Test_one(test);
                    shouldBreak = true; // have to break here
                break;
                default:
                break;
            } 
             if (shouldBreak) break; //To break this while
        }
        break;

    }
    break;
    }
```

Comment: What part isn't working? From what you've written the loop won't break only if  case 0 or case 1 is true and we never reach case 2.

Comment: where i have marked as "//have to break here" i have to stop that while loop there.

Comment: Change `while(true)...` by `do...while(!shouldBreak)`.

Comment: There is no need to change `while(true)`. I feel the problem is with how you're handling cases.

Comment: ok i will try, but shouldBreak will become true after that case 2 executes, how does it works?

Comment: Yes, it will become true. I feel that case 2 is never getting executed and it only goes for other cases or default.

Comment: It's a lot easier to control this kind of thing if you nicely place each [switch statement]/[loop body] in its own function. It lets you take advantage of `return` without having to add all kinds of flags or labels for breaking.

Comment: no, case 2 is working, the statement before break is working, it is reaching case 2. @AakashVerma

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `while(true)` with `while(!shouldBreak)` as a `break` statement only breaks out of the inner-most loop / switch / while etc.

For more details see e.g. [Difference between break and continue statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462373/difference-between-break-and-continue-statement)

Answer (score 1):

Just use your flag in the while check:

```
switch ()
  case  
    bool shouldLoop = true
    while (shouldLoop)
      switch
        case 
          if 
            shouldLoop = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using label with the while loop as below :

```
label:
    While()
    {
      for()
      {
         break label;
      }
    }
```