# Difference between return and break inside ifs in a for loop

Tags: java, android, for-loop, return, break

I'm studing a code wich has this code:

```
public void add(StockUpdate newStockUpdate) {

    for (StockUpdate stockUpdate : data) {
        if (stockUpdate.getStockSymbol().equals(newStockUpdate.getStockSymbol())) {
            if (stockUpdate.getPrice().equals(newStockUpdate.getPrice())) {
                return;
            }
            break;
        }
    }

    /* data.add mathod checks the new data against the existing data. If no change is found, the update is discarded. */
    this.data.add(0, newStockUpdate);
    notifyItemInserted(0);
}
```

I just want to know if the `return` and the `break` statements in this code are, in any way, different from each other. Because I tested a similar example outside this code and both `return` and `break` stopped the loop and terminates the function.

Comment: `break` will break the loop, not return from the entire method. So the next line that is executed would be the `this.data.add...`

Comment: To give some food for thought, you can also have a look at the [`continue` keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/q/462373/4906586)

Comment: Thanks @Rogue! this is what I wanted to know. The same as the response I  gave the green checkmark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`break` stops just the loop; `return` stops the entire method.

The juxtaposition of `break` and `return` like this makes it quite hard to follow the logic of the `add` method. Consider that the following might be easier to follow:

```
public void add(StockUpdate newStockUpdate) {
  StockUpdate stockUpdate = findStockUpdateBySymbol(newStockUpdate.getStockSymbol());
  if (stockUpdate != null
      && stockUpdate.getPrice().equals(newStockUpdate.getPrice())) {
    return;
  }

  /* data.add mathod checks the new data against the existing data. If no change is found, the update is discarded. */
  this.data.add(0, newStockUpdate);
  notifyItemInserted(0);
}

// On non-android, it's easier to do this with a stream/findFirst.
private StockUpdate findStockUpdateBySymbol(StockSymbol sym) {
    for (StockUpdate stockUpdate : data) {
        if (stockUpdate.getStockSymbol().equals(sym)) {
            return stockUpdate;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'd say that this is easier to follow (whilst being slightly more verbose) because it is separating out the different things that are being done: you're trying to find a matching stock symbol; and if you find that, do other stuff. Mixing that all together into the one loop obfuscates that intent.